# Style and Enumerators

Tags: c++, enums, coding-style

So, in the process of taking a data-structures class (in C++), my professor wanted us to manipulate a linked list of playing cards. That doesn't matter however, what I am interested in is why she did not use an enumerator to represent the suites.

In her code, she used strings to hold the suite of a card. This seemed inefficient because she wanted us to sort them based on suite, under the circumstances, it would have been considerably easier if she had used an enumerated type instead of a string. The string did not offer any help either, because in printing the suite, she output a Unicode character, roughly doubling the length of her function, simply because she did not use an enum.

Is there any reason for her to have done this, or does she simply have strange preferences when it comes to code style?

Comment: It would probably have been easier to ask her. Good teachers like inquisitive questions, and bad teachers aren't worth listening to. As for the problem itself, I can't see a reason to use strings for that, myself.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not asking the professor? She'd know best about her reasons for doing things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want to know what your professor's reasoning is, you have to ask your professor.  I can only speculate.

But if I were to speculate, I would guess that there are two possible reasons why your professor chose to use strings as descriptors for these attributes.

1. She is trying to keep the code simple and easy for newbie C++ programmers to understand.  Whether the means meet the goal is debateable.
2. (Personal bias alert) Professors and others in academia, with no real-world experience, often do and teach things that I would consider to be highly sub-optimal.

Comment: I was going to say something similar to #2 ... but decided to hold my tongue :)

Comment: Thank you for that confirmation on #2.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that she either had not considered that approach or that she wanted to test your ability to work with sorting strings.

Code examples might help in that they might clarify what she did and what you think she should have done.

Answer (score 0):

The likely answer is that she just didn't think about the problem she was using to demonstrate whatever she is trying to teach you.  That is, she wanted you to focus on sorting (for example), and probably took some code written by someone else and just adapted it to that purpose without much thought.